# Show latest added item in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select ng-init="somethingHere = options[0]" ng-model="somethingHere" ng-options="option.name for option in options"></select>
```

In short i need something like this without ng-init,

http://plnkr.co/edit/f29i1Tz07OHMxfYDR4qc?p=preview

I need to display the latest added letter, if I added C, then show C, if D is added then display D and so on.. anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** :

Try this :

```
<select ng-model="selected">
    <option ng-repeat="v in letters" ng-selected="$last">{{v}}</option>
</select>
```

don't name your ng-model like the variable you're looping over.

Comment: Tried that one, the only thing that is selected is: 
`<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>` the default value..

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the selected value in a separate variable on the scope, and then when you add a letter, just update the value of that separated variable with the last element of the array.

See this:http://plnkr.co/edit/MGm9DVI7tv4eqPWnAgPi?p=preview

```
 $scope.selectedLetter = $scope.letters[$scope.letters.length-1]
```